# NumPy `a.resize` adds non-zero values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was writing an adjacency matrix, and was trying to use the `np.ndarray.resize` to add all-zero rows and columns. According to the [`np.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) documentation:

> If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of a. **Note that this behavior is different from a.resize(new_shape) which fills with zeros instead of repeated copies of a.

However, I tried both the `np.resize` and the `np.ndarray.resize`, and they both add an unexpected value. My question is **Why is this happening?** (I know how to go around the problem, but I don't know why it's happening).

```py
import numpy as np

class MatrixGraph:
  def __init__(self):
    self.nodes = np.array([], dtype=int)

  def add_node(self, node):
    if node >= len(self.nodes):
      # self.nodes.resize((node+1, node+1))
      self.nodes = np.resize(self.nodes, (node+1, node+1))

  def from_edges_list(self, edges, bidirectional=False):
    for edge in edges:
      self.add_node(edge[0])
      self.add_node(edge[1])
      self.nodes[edge[0], edge[1]] = 1
      if bidirectional:
        self.nodes[edge[1], edge[0]] = 1

  def edges_list(self):
    return list(zip(*np.where(self.nodes)))

g = MatrixGraph()
g.from_edges_list(((1, 2), (1, 4), (4, 2), (2, 5), (5, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (6, 6)))

print(g.edges_list())
print(g.nodes)
```

Prints

```
[(0, 5), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 6), (4, 2), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 3), (6, 6)]
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1]]
```

Notice that there are a lot of edges that I didn't try adding. Moreover, I don't even have the 0 node, and it still populates it.

**Edit 1**: Here are the visualizations of the expected graph and the graph that the `MatrixGraph` frankensteins:

Expected:

[image: Expectation]

Got:

[image: Reality]

**Edit 2:** When using the `np.ndarray.resize` (commented out in the example code above), I get a different result (still incorrect tho):

```
[(0, 5), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 6), (4, 6), (6, 6)]
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: The zero fill makes some sense when expanding a 1d array.  Or adding new rows.  But if you change the number of columns data will be shifted. The new zeros always appear at the end - in a flattened sense.

Comment: Use `np.pad` to add columns or rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# this example was taken from ndarray.resize doc
b = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
b.resize(2, 3) # new_shape parameter doesn't have to be a tuple
print(b)
#array([[0, 1, 2],
#       [3, 0, 0]])
```

The new array is filled with zeros, but the data changes aswell. The new array contains the original data, but in a row-wise manner.
Simple workaround:

```
def add_node(self, node):
    if node >= len(self.nodes):
        original_len = len(self.nodes)
        if original_len == 0:     # when array empty, assuming square matrix
            self.nodes = np.zeros((node, node))
        else:     # this adds zeros according to missing rows and cols
            to_be_added = node - len(self.nodes) + 1
            self.nodes = np.hstack((self.nodes, np.zeros((original_len, to_be_added))))
            self.nodes = np.vstack((self.nodes, np.zeros((to_be_added, original_len+to_be_added))))
```

Comment: Yea, I have a similar workaround, which works, though not ideal. My question is why do I see the behavior

Comment: Emmm, that's literally what I put in the question as well... Not sure what you are trying to say. Elaborate?

Comment: yup, noticed that, sorry... this is how the ndarray works, which is not ussable for your application
b = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
b.resize(2, 3) # new_shape parameter doesn't have to be a tuple
b
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#       [3, 0, 0]])

Comment: according to doc: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html
3rd example

Comment: I edited the post... hope I was able to describe how the ndarray.resize works

Answer (score 2):

You have an array, e.g. 2×2 matrix

```
1 2
3 4
```

You *expected* — after resizing it to 3×3 — that the original matrix *will remain the same* and zeroes will fill positions *to the right and down of it,* i.e. you expected as a result the matrix

```
1 2 0
3 4 0
0 0 0
```

**But it is not the case.** NumPy keeps its arrays in memory as a continuous sequence of elements (a vector), and info about its shape as a meta info.

It means that the original 2×2 matrix keeps in memory as

```
1 2 3 4
```

and after resizing it fill it by zeroes (or by repeating it in the case of using the ndarray method instead of a NumPy function) **after the last position of its memory representation**

```
1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then show it (and works with it by index calculations) as

```
1 2 3
4 0 0
0 0 0
```

---

**How to correct your method** `add_node()`:

1. First approach — create a new, zero-filled matrix, and then place the original one to the left upper corner of it:

   ```
   def add_node(self, node):
     if node >= len(self.nodes):
       rows, cols = self.nodes.shape
       temp = np.zeros((node+1, node+1), dtype=int)
       temp[:rows, :cols] = self.nodes
       self.nodes = temp
   ```
2. Second approach — use the NumPy's `pad()` function — you may control, where you want to pad and how many rows / columns<sup>*)</sup>:

   ```
   def add_node(self, node):
     if node >= len(self.nodes):
     to_add = node + 1 - len(self.nodes)
     self.nodes = np.pad(self.nodes, ((0, to_add), (0, to_add)))
   ```

   *The explanation:*

   For 2-dimensional array one form of `np.pad()` is

   ```
   np.pad(array, ((before_top, after_bottom), (before_left, after_right)))
   ```

   e.g after the `a = np.pad(a, ((2, 4), (0, 3)))` command

   ```
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0
               1 2   will     1, 2, 0, 0, 0
               3 4   become   3, 4, 0, 0, 0
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   ```

---

*<sup>)</sup> Thanks to [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s comment.

Comment: No need to remove pad elements, just use `np.pad(a,((0,1),(0,1)))` to fully control what's added on all 4 sides.

Comment: @RafazZ, you're welcome. Please see my simplified 2nd approach in my edited answer  thanks to [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s comment.